# Erro NullReferenceException em join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, nullpointerexception

Criei um join em `LINQ` pra criar uma `List`:

```
(from p in listaProcedimento
    join pd in oListaprocedimentodetalhe on p.codigo equals pd.codigoProcedimento into pd1
    from pd2 in pd1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ProcedimentoDetalhe()
    {
        codigoDetalhe = pd2.codigoDetalhe == null ? "000" : "012",
        codigoProcedimento = p.codigo,
        descricao = p.descricao,
        idadeMax = p.idadeMax,
        idadeMin = p.idadeMin
    }).OrderBy(p => p.descricao)
      .ToList();
```

Recebo o erro dizendo que `pd2 was null`, sendo que eu já tentei corrigir isso na linha: `pd2.codigoDetalhe == null ? "000" : "012"`.

Porque não está funcionando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou achando esse código estranho, mas não está fazendo o que imagina. Não está analisando se o `p2` é `null` está analisando se um campo dele (`pd2.codigoDetalhe`) é nulo, o que é tarde demais porque o próprio `p2` é nulo e já dá erro e não pode analisar seu campo que não existe já que seria um campo de algo nulo. O correto seria:

```
codigoDetalhe = pd2 == null ? "000" : "012",
```

Ainda assim não sei se esta é a solução final, mas resolve a questão que está na pergunta.

Você pode garantir que o campo nunca é nulo? Se não puder tem que verificar ele também, assim:

```
codigoDetalhe = pd2 == null || pd2.codigoDetalhe == null ? "000" : "012",
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/DefaultValue.cs).

Comment: Não resolveu pois está só listou os códigos onde `pd2 == "012"`. Vou postar as classes pra detalhar melhor a pergunta

Comment: Exatamente o que eu falei, você colocou uma pergunta, resolveu esse problema, recebeu 3 respostas, agora quer mudar a pergunta e invalidar as 3 respostas, não pode.

Comment: Entendi, vou criar outra pergunta então

Answer (score 2):

Porque o que está nulo é o `pd2`, não a propriedade `pd2.codigoDetalhe`.

Tente assim:

```
codigoDetalhe = pd2 == null ? "000" : "012",
```

Comment: Não resolveu pois está só listou os códigos onde `pd2 == "012"`. Vou postar as classes pra detalhar melhor a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Mude sua linha para compara pd2  e codigoDetalhe se são iguais a null

`codigoDetalhe = pd2 == null && pd2.codigoDetalhe == null ? "000" : "012",`

Uma coisa curiosa é você trocar o valor de codigoDetalhe por outro valor.

Se você esta tralhando com listas faria algo mais performático assim.

```
(from p in listaProcedimento
    select new ProcedimentoDetalhe()
    {
        codigoDetalhe = (oListaprocedimentodetalhe.any(pd => p.codigo == pd.codigoProcedimento && pd.codigoDetalhe != null) ? "012" : "000" ,
        codigoProcedimento = p.codigo,
        descricao = p.descricao,
        idadeMax = p.idadeMax,
        idadeMin = p.idadeMin
    }).OrderBy(p => p.descricao)
      .ToList();
```

Dentro do seu select faria a verificarão do seu campo .

```
(oListaprocedimentodetalhe.any(pd => p.codigo == pd.codigoProcedimento && pd.codigoDetalhe ! null)
```